# Trouble installing psycopg2 on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I tried using this:
http://stickpeople.com/projects/python/win-psycopg/

But had no luck. I even did easy_install psycopg2-2.6.1...(the same name as the 64 bit link on the website).

I am using Windows 8.1 and Python 3.5. I am not familiar with some of the topics I googled like virtual environments and such... I typically just use anaconda and things works. This is the first module that didn't work out of the box.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:xxxxxxx@localhost:xxxx/xxxxxxx')
```

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Comment: There are some conda packages available (just not in the default channel): https://anaconda.org/search?q=psycopg2&sort=ndownloads&sort_order=-1&reverse=true. I would just try to install some of these and try out which one works (for me the one of jonrowland has worked in the past)

Comment: I tried that. I get a hint which says:

The following packages conflict with each other :
psycopg2
python 3.5*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes the installed binaries are not up-to-date.

When it happens, a workaround is to add the PostgreSQL binary path (for instance `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin`) to the path variables.

You may need [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) if you don't know how to add path variable on windows.

Comment: thanks - I did this and I uninstalled Anaconda and completely reinstalled python. I then used 7zip and extracted this file which I downloaded: psycopg2-2.6.1-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl. Two folders were contained inside of it which I then pasted into my site_packages folder in my (newly installed) Anaconda directory. 

I'm not sure what exactly fixed it but everything is working now. FYI for anyone else having trouble with Windows, Python 3.5 and psycopg2 (for sqlalchemy and pandas to_sql exports)